# How to make a shoppingcart that can be saved and shared in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to build a database for a school project and i want the option to save carts that can be shared with other users via URL. The problem is creating the database for this, i have one solution atm, but it feels clumsy and i would like to see if someone has a better option.

My current solution is

| Products | Cart | Productamount | Cartlist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ProductID (Primary) | CartID (Primary) | ProduktID (Foreign) | CartID (Foreign) |
| Name | Productamount1 (Foreign) | Amount | MemberID (Foreign) |
| Price | Productamount2 (Foreign) | (Both of the above combined acts as Primary Key) |  |
| Description | Productamount3 (Foreign) |  |  |
| Category | .... up to 10 |  |  |

There are also a Member and Order table.

The part that feels weird to me is the current relationship between the Cart and the Productamount tables, i thought about merging them and simply adding 10 amount columns to the cart but i thought this might make a lot of unnecessary NULL values.

I know that for a school project the actual amount of data stored will never be  enough to actually matter but i am interested in what would be the best option for a genuinely large database.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having ProductAmount and CartList tables, could you just have the Cart table looks like this?

| CartID (PK) | ProductID (PK, FK) | MemberID (FK) | ProductAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

You'll have one row per product per cart, and instead of using the schema to enforce a maximum of 10 products, it would be better to have your application handle that. Your Product table stays the same, and you end up with only 2 tables.

Comment: I agree, although I would still use a third table for the CartID-MemberID relationship. If needed, other data about the cart can be stored in that table (f.e. creation date or anything else).

Comment: My idea with the Cartlist was so that it would be possible for the same cart to belong to more than one costumer, the way you suggest i would probably still need the Cartlist though in order to keep the saved Cart strung together for later viewing though.